# Why this code for html checkbox works for Firefox and Chrome, but not for IE?

Tags: html, checkbox

This is related to my previous question : [Why html checkbox function only works in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596000/why-html-checkbox-function-only-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox-or-chrome)

Why the following code does not work in IE :

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkAdvSearch(checked)
  {
    console.log("Test");
    if (checked==1)
    {
      document.getElementById("searchTerm2").style.display='';
      document.getElementById("searchField2").style.display='';
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("searchTerm2").style.display='none';
      document.getElementById("searchField2").style.display='none';

      document.getElementById("searchTerm2").value='';
      document.getElementById("searchField2").value='Client Name';
    }
  }
</script>

  <input type="checkbox" name="advSearch" onclick="checkAdvSearch(this.checked);" checked />Advanced Search
  <input type="text" id="searchTerm2" value="" />
  <select id="searchField2" value="clientName" >
    <option>Client Name</option>
    <option>Policy Number</option>
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

When I uncheck the box, the other 2 items are supposed to go away, but in IE there is no response, why ?

Edit :

Thanks to Huangism, I found the following message, and clicked it to allow access, now it works OK.

[image]

Comment: Which IE version? From the screenshot on the other question, it looks like a lower version of IE, like IE 8 which does not have `console` so your `console.log()` would return a js error and your code will not work as expected

Comment: My IE version is 11. But I also tried it with IE 10, didn't work either.

Comment: I just tested your code on IE 11 and I don't see any issues http://jsfiddle.net/fnqa13wn/

Comment: Something strange is happening, same code, when I opened my IE 11 and tried it, didn't work, but when I opened another tab and tried your site, it works, what can be the issue ?

Comment: Check for errors on IE when you click

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, by allowing IE blocked content.